# SQL View to show interval of 12 months and by year

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-view

Right now one of the other programmers wrote this view to show interval of 6months. How do i write this so that it shows interval of 12 months grouped by month but only for year 2011

I'd like to copy it for a separate view of 12 months grouped by month but only for year 2012

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`%` 
SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `vw_dash_bymonth`AS
select 
  month(from_unixtime(`tbl_services`.`datetime`)) AS` month1`,
  date_format(from_unixtime(`tbl_services`.`datetime`),'%Y') AS` year1`,
  date_format(from_unixtime(`tbl_services`.`datetime`),'%d') AS `day1`,
 `tbl_services`.`datetime` AS `realdate`,sum(`tbl_services`.`gallons`) AS `gallons`,
 count(0) AS `service`,
 round(avg(`tbl_services`.`gallons`),1) AS `average`
from `tbl_services`
where (from_unixtime(`tbl_services`.`datetime`) > (now() - interval 6 month))
group by month(from_unixtime(`tbl_services`.`datetime`))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the where clause

```
where (from_unixtime(`tbl_services`.`datetime`) > (now() - interval 6 month))
```

I believe this is getting the dates from everything from 6 months ago until today. If you want 12 months in 2011 I think you could replace that line with something like:

```
where (from_unixtime(`tbl_services`.`datetime`) >= DATE('2011-01-01 00:00:00')) 
  AND (from_unixtime(`tbl_services`.`datetime`) < DATE('2012-01-01 00:00:00'))
```

Although I don't know MySQL (just SQLServer) so if this doesn't work, hopefully someone else can tell me where I went wrong.

---

It can be simplified to:

```
where (from_unixtime(`tbl_services`.`datetime`) >= '2011-01-01') 
  AND (from_unixtime(`tbl_services`.`datetime`) < '2012-01-01')
```

Comment: Did it mention where / what part?

Comment: When i insert that it says there's a syntax error with the next line on

group by month(from_unixtime(`tbl_services`.`datetime`))

Comment: Okay I am guessing it may be because I used DATE and not DATETIME, I will look into what from_unixtime returns. For the time being can you try replacing DATE with DATETIME ?

Comment: No DATETIME gives me an error on the round bracket

DATETIME('2011-01-01

Comment: Okay this is possibly a longshot but try replacing `DATE(` with `from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`

Comment: Some parenthesis are missing at the ends.

Comment: no go, error on group next line

where (from_unixtime(`tbl_services`.`datetime`) > (from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2011-01-01 00:00:00')) AND (from_unixtime(`tbl_services`.`datetime`) < (from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-01-01 00:00:00'))
group by month(from_unixtime(`tbl_services`.`datetime`))

Comment: You have extra parenthesis I believe, remove the ( from in front of both of your (from_unixtime that you just added

Comment: @ypercube you are right I was missing parenthesis, do you happen to know if the whole where clause needs to be in parenthesis? Hector try the new edit where the parenthesis are fixed and see if it works

Comment: Now errer on curved bracket after DATETIME --- where from_unixtime(`tbl_services`.`datetime`) > (DATETIME('2011-01-01 00:00:00')) AND from_unixtime(`tbl_services`.`datetime`) < (DATETIME('2012-01-01 00:00:00'))
group by month(from_unixtime(`tbl_services`.`datetime`)) --- sorry for my syntax

Comment: No, you don't need anything extra. And you could replace `DATE('2011-01-01 00:00:00')` with just `'2011-01-01'`

Comment: Small correction. The `> DATE(...)` should be: `>= DATE(...)`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT FROM_UNIXTIME('date','%m-%Y') AS month,
COUNT(`id`) AS count
FROM 'blog'
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month DESC LIMIT 0,12
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    MONTH( UNIX_TIMESTAMP( t.`datetime`) ) AS month1,
    DATE_FORMAT( UNIX_TIMESTAMP( t.`datetime`), '%Y' ) AS year1,
    DATE_FORMAT( UNIX_TIMESTAMP( t.`datetime`), '%d') AS day1,
    t.`datetime` AS realdate,
    SUM(t.gallons) AS gallons,
    COUNT(*) AS `service`,
    ROUND( AVG( t.gallons ), 1 ) AS `average`
FROM 
      tbl_services AS t
  CROSS JOIN
      ( SELECT 2011 AS YearToCheck
      ) AS c
WHERE t.`datetime` >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP( MAKEDATE( YearToCheck, 1 ) )
  AND t.`datetime` < UNIX_TIMESTAMP( MAKEDATE( YearToCheck+1, 1 ) )
GROUP BY MONTH( FROM_UNIXTIME( t.`datetime` ) )
```